# Probability of $X>1/2$ and $X<1/2$

Tags: probability

I have a PDF like this

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{2}{3}x^2 \ \text{ if } 0<x<1\\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

How do I find $P\left(X<\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $P\left(X>\frac{1}{2}\right)$?

Is it correct to do $P\left(X<\frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{2}{3}x^2 dx$ and $P\left(X<\frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_{1/2}^{2}\frac{2}{3}x^2 dx$?

The question I really want answered is: The limits in the probability and the PDF are "<", not "$\leq$", so can I just integrate to 2 for example?

Comment: You need to fix this expression $|0<x<|1$

Comment: And you need to fix your PDF $-$ it doesn't satisfy $\int f = 1$.

Comment: The set $x=\frac12$ has null measure.

Comment: I think your function is not a valid PDF.

Comment: @amWhy, those \left's and \right's make absolutely no difference to the output. Why did you bother?

Answer (score 1):

$P(X=1/2) = 0$ for any continuous random variable $X$.

More generally

$P(X=a) = 0$ for any continuous random variable $X$ and for any real number $a$.

So whether you write $P(X \lt 1/2)$ or $P(X \le 1/2)$
it doesn't really matter, they are the same number.

The same is true for

$P(a \lt X \lt b)$
$P(a \lt X \le b)$
$P(a \le X \lt b)$
$P(a \le X \le b)$

These are all equal numbers.

$P(a \lt X \lt b) = P(a \lt X \le b) = P(a \le X \lt b) = P(a \le X \le b)$

This part looks correct:

$P(X<\frac{1}{2})=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{2}{3}x^2 dx$

This writing of yours is incorrect:

$P(X<\frac{1}{2})=\int_{1/2}^{2}\frac{2}{3}x^2 dx$